# C# вызов методов предка

Tags: c#

Чисто вопрос интереса ради. Возможно ли вызвать метод старее чем предок из потомка? Чтонибудь типа

```
(КлассПраПраДедушка)base.МетодКласса()
```

или

```
base.base.МетодКласса()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно.

Например, так:

```
КлассПраПраДедушка grandpa = this;
grandpa.МетодКласса();
```

Ну или просто `((КлассПраПраДедушка)this).МетодКласса();`

Если `МетодКласса` не перекрыт при помощи `new`, то можно, разумеется, просто `МетодКласса();`.

Синтаксиса, подобного `base`, для спуска дальше вниз по иерархии, нету. То есть, вам нужно указать точный тип предка.

---

Как правильно подсказывает @AntonShchyrov, для случая *виртуального* переопределённого метода, вызвать метод метод предка дальше, чем `base`, средствами языка невозможно.

Можно сделать грубый хак через рефлексию:

```
class Grandpa
{
    public virtual void Do() => Console.WriteLine("Grandpa.Do");
}

class Father : Grandpa
{
    public override void Do() => Console.WriteLine("Father.Do");
}

class Child : Father
{
    public void CallGrandpa()
    {
        ((Action)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(Action),
            this,
            typeof(Grandpa).GetMethod("Do").MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer())).Invoke();
    }
}
```

Никогда не делайте так. О причинах, почему плохо вызывать *что попало*, говорит Эрик Липперт [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2327821/276994).

---

Прямой вызов через рефлексию не работает, и вызывает в реальности переопределённый метод. Хитрость с `MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer()` позаимствована [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14415506/276994).

Comment: дошло. спасибо.

Comment: @АлексейКременецкий: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Глупый вопрос. А если метод виртуальный?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov: Хорошее уточнение! Тогда невозможно по идее.

Comment: По задумке виртуальных методов, вызвать метод предка можно только внутри него самого, при приведении же реальный класс объекта и таблица методов не меняются, а отдельного способа как при явной реализации интерфейсов нет

Comment: А кстати, методы которые планируются к `override` рекомендуют делать строго `protected` а не `public` именно по той причине, чтоб нельзя было у прадедушек вызывать такие методы извне, как думаете?

Comment: @АлексейКременецкий если ответ вам помог, отметье его галочкой

Comment: @Bulson: Вы имеете в виду [это](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#protected-virtuals)? Я не в курсе, я использую и `public virtual` тоже.

Comment: @VladD Наткнулся на такое [видео](https://youtu.be/-13KJSZuR9k?t=14m58s) и там такая рекомендация что ли. Сам я никогда о таком не задумывался, а тут такое. Вот к слову и вспомнилось.

Comment: @Bulson: Ага, это оговаривается здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/virtual-members. А и правда, почему? Может, имеет смысл задать вопрос.

Comment: @VladD о, нашли таки, а я как не старался только на описание модификаторов доступа попадал. Конечно можно и задать вопрос, но в каком ключе? И кто на него ответит? :)

Comment: @Bulson: Задал вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749392/10105

Comment: @VladD да, спасибо, прочитал. Ответ rdorn мне кажется достаточно убедительным. Сам же я затрудняюсь сказать что-либо вразумительное.